# How to get a vertical bar chart with the sum of rows grouped by month

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, google-spreadsheets

I have a spreadsheet with over 300 rows, and in each row I have a Created At column with this date format: 20/Apr/21 5:34PM.

I would like to have a vertical chart that is the sum of the rows for each of the months and years. So, if there are 4 rows that happened in the month of April of 2021, I would see a vertical chart with the Y axis being 4.

What is the best way to:

- Remove the day and time, because I don't really care about the day and time?
- Plot this data in a vertical bar chart, where the X axis are the months and years and the Y chart is the number of rows in that month and year.

I'm using Google spreadsheets.

Comment: Plzz [edit] your post & share some sample data will help us to understand the data orientation,, one hint is you need to get unique Month & Year & Count respective Row and use these to make chart but not the original data !!

Comment: Two words: Pivot Table.
Not sure if Google sheets will do charts from pivotted data but if it will, then pivot by date and group by month and year, summarise data with a count.